# Converting a fully connected neural network with variable number of hidden layers from tensorflow to pytorch

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, mlp

I recently started learning `pytorch` and I am trying to convert a part of a large script including coding a MLP with variable number of hidden layers from `Tensorflow` to `pytorch`.

```
import tensorflow as tf

### Base neural network                                                                                                                  
def init_mlp(layer_sizes, std=.01, bias_init=0.):
    params = {'w':[], 'b':[]}
    for n_in, n_out in zip(layer_sizes[:-1], layer_sizes[1:]):
        params['w'].append(tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_in, n_out], stddev=std)))
        params['b'].append(tf.Variable(tf.mul(bias_init, tf.ones([n_out,]))))
    return params


def mlp(X, params):
    h = [X]
    for w,b in zip(params['w'][:-1], params['b'][:-1]):
        h.append( tf.nn.relu( tf.matmul(h[-1], w) + b ) )
        #h.append( tf.nn.tanh( tf.matmul(h[-1], w) + b ) ) 
    return tf.matmul(h[-1], params['w'][-1]) + params['b'][-1]


def compute_nll(x, x_recon_linear):
    return tf.reduce_sum(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(x_recon_linear, x), reduction_indices=1, keep_dims=True)


def gauss_cross_entropy(mean_post, std_post, mean_prior, std_prior):
    d = (mean_post - mean_prior)
    d = tf.mul(d,d)
    return tf.reduce_sum(-tf.div(d + tf.mul(std_post,std_post),(2.*std_prior*std_prior)) - tf.log(std_prior*2.506628), reduction_indices=1, keep_dims=True)
```

- how could I write down similarly weights and bias variables and attach them in each hidden layer in `pytorch`?
- how could I convert `gauss_cross_entropy` and `compute_nll`
  functions as well (finding equivalent syntax)?

Are these two codes compatible?

```
import numpy as np
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as func
from torch.distributions import Normal, Categorical, Independent
from copy import 

device = "cpu"
if torch.cuda.is_available():
    device = "cuda:0"
    if torch.cuda.device_count() > 1:
        net = nn.DataParallel(net)
net.to(device)
def init_mlp(layer_sizes, std=.01, bias_init=0.):
    params = {'w':[], 'b':[]}
    for n_in, n_out in zip(layer_sizes[:-1], layer_sizes[1:]):
        params['w'].append(torch.tensor(Normal([n_in, n_out], torch.tensor([std])) ,requires_grad=True))
        params['b'].append(torch.tensor(torch.mul(bias_init, torch.ones([n_out,])),requires_grad=True))
    return params


def mlp(X, params):
    h = [X]
    for w,b in zip(params['w'][:-1], params['b'][:-1]):
        h.append( torch.nn.ReLU( tf.matmul(h[-1], w) + b ) )
    return torch.matmul(h[-1], params['w'][-1]) + params['b'][-1]

def compute_nll(x, x_recon_linear):
    return torch.sum(func.binary_cross_entropy_with_logits(x_recon_linear, x), reduction_indices=1, keep_dims=True)


def gauss_cross_entropy(mu_post, sigma_post, mu_prior, sigma_prior):
    d = (mu_post - mu_prior)
    d = torch.mul(d,d)
    return torch.sum(-torch.div(d + torch.mul(sigma_post,sigma_post),(2.*sigma_prior*sigma_prior)) - torch.log(sigma_prior*2.506628), reduction_indices=1, keep_dims=True)
```

- What is the substitute function for `tf.placeholder` in `pytorch`? For instance here:

  ```
  class VAE(object):

   def __init__(self, hyperParams):

       self.X = tf.placeholder("float", [None, hyperParams['input_d']])
       self.prior = hyperParams['prior']
       self.K = hyperParams['K']

       self.encoder_params = self.init_encoder(hyperParams)
       self.decoder_params = self.init_decoder(hyperParams)
  ```

and also how should I change `tf.shape` in this line: `tf.random_normal(tf.shape(self.sigma[-1]))`

Comment: Which part of the code do you have trouble with converting? Have you looked at [PyTorch available builtin layers](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html) yet?

Comment: @Ivan I tried to add more details to my question if it helps to clear up stuff.

Comment: If you search for MLP PyTorch on the internet, surely you come upon [nn.Linear](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Linear.html) the builtin for a fully connected layer in PyTorch. Do you want to build your model by hand or with existing layers, your tf code suggests the former.

Comment: @ivan I did a lot of googling before posting the question here. I know the rules in this community and as you said I want to build it by hand.

Comment: Here is my advice, start by defining the first layer of your MLP: this should be two tensors `W` and `b`. Initialize those two tensors, then compute the forward pass `W*x+b` (check the shapes). That should be a start. When you've tried I'm sure you will get some help here. Right now, I'm afraid you haven't shown enough enough effort in your question.

Comment: @Ivan is this conversion correct?

Comment: Good to see you made some progress! I'll post an answer as quickly as possible.

Answer (score 1):

- > How could I write down similar weights and bias variables and attach them in each hidden layer in PyTorch?

  An easier way to define those is to create a *list* containing the params as (weight, bias) *tuple*s:

  ```
  def init_mlp(layer_sizes, std=.01, bias_init=0.):
      params = []
      for n_in, n_out in zip(layer_sizes[:-1], layer_sizes[1:]):
          params.append([
              nn.init.normal_(torch.empty(n_in, n_out)).requires_grad_(True),
              torch.empty(n_out).fill_(bias_init).requires_grad_(True)])
      return params
  ```

  Above I define my parameters as 'empty' (created with uninitialized data) tensors with [`torch.empty`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.empty.html). I have used in-place functions such as [`nn.init.normal_`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.init.html?highlight=nn%20init#torch.nn.init.normal_) (there are [many others](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/search.html?q=nn.init&check_keywords=yes&area=default#) available) and [torch.Tensor.fill_](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.fill_.html) to fill the tensor with an arbitrary value (maybe it is `.mul_(bias_init)` you are looking for, based on your TensorFlow sample?).

  For the inference code, you don't actually need to store the intermediate layer results:

  ```
  def mlp(x, params):
      for i, (W, b) in enumerate(params):
          x = x@W + b
          if i < len(params) - 1:
              x = torch.relu(x)
      return x
  ```

---

- > How could I convert `gauss_cross_entropy` and `compute_nll` functions as well (finding equivalent syntax)?

  You can use PyTorch functions and mathematical operators to define your logic. For `compute_loss` you were using the built-in, which actually does not require summation after it, by default the losses of the batch elements are averaged.

  ```
  def compute_loss(y_pred, y_true):
      return F.binary_cross_entropy_with_logits(y_pred, y_true)
  ```

---

- > What is the substitute function for `tf.placeholder` in Pytorch?

  You don't have placeholders in PyTorch, you compute your outputs explicitly using PyTorch operators, then you should be able to backpropagate through those operators and get the gradients for each parameter.

---

- > How should I change tf.shape in this line: `tf.random_normal(tf.shape(self.sigma[-1]))`

  Function [tf.shape](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/shape) returns the shape of the tensor, in PyTorch you call `torch.Tensor.shape` or by calling `torch.Tensor.size`: *i.e.* `self.sigma[-1].shape` or `self.sigma[-1].size()`.